# Related to abinitio graph and pset

Tags: ab-initio

can you please help me to get the answer of below question:
I have a generic graph which has many .psets ,if my graph has failed then is there any way to know which pset has failed.

Comment: Generally the start of the logs has all the information like which graph was executed and the related pset.
Logs should have all the required information about which pset was executed
and with what reason the graph failed. Please check the failure logs in details (or share here if available).

Comment: When you execute a generic graph using pset, graph is invoked by pset name not by graph name.

Answer (score 0):

When a pset or graph is run using the Ab Initio environment, one of the logs is the archived pset:

```
info : Input pset archived to ...
```

The first line of that file contains the original pset or graph name as the last field, separated by `|`. You can use `head -1` and `awk` (escape the `|` with `\`):

```
head -1 /path-to-archived-input.pset | awk -F\| '{print $NF}'
/u/fdavis/ab/private_sand/test4/mp/3-sec-running-graph.pset
```

Use the basename command to get just the pset name:

```
basename $(head -1 /path-to-archived-input.pset | awk -F\| '{print $NF}')
3-sec-running-graph.pset
```